# Labels not showing in Xcode Simulator

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I have a label in my storyboard and it shows up fine in the previews of multiple iPhones and an iPad, but when i run the simulator the label does not show up. Why is this happening?

Here is a link to a video I made showing this (hopefully it helps show the problem):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-M2clPf4Ms

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: post the code for that viewcontroller and also print out the property of the label.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it doesn't show up when your run it on devices either (correct me if I'm wrong!). Without seeing your code, it looks like it may be a constraints issue.

You can debug what's going on by creating a UIOutlet from the label to your view controller, creating a breakpoint during the view controller execution (in viewDidAppear), and printing out the label properties in the debug window with the command:

```
po myLabel
```

In particular, whether the label is hidden and the size/position of the frame is of interest.